# Keyboard goes out randomly

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, acer-aspire

I own an Acer Aspire laptop, running windows 10. Occasionally, without any pattern or obvious root cause, the keyboard will stop working. Restarting the computer fixes the issue. I have checked all my drivers, and all the connections. What else causes this issue, and how do I fix it?

As a note: The computer was reimaged using a hard drive from a different model after the original hard drive in the Aspire failed.

Comment: Could be an OS issue or an hardware issue. Try running a Linux Live CD and see if the same behaviour pattern follows. If it does, it is likely an OS issue. Did you also check the USB port in which the keyboard is connected (check for loose connections, dry solder etc)

Comment: Its not a usb keyboard, it is the built in keyboard. All the connectors are solidly together, and from what I can tell the solder for the wiring on each end is still firmly connected to the boards. Will test a kali live boot and see if the issue persists

Comment: Did you try the Live CD option?

Comment: I used a kali live boot for many hours amd did not encounter the issue. It is to be noted though that the issue does occur randomly on windows with no discernable pattern. Sometimes it goes days or weeks without occuring, other times it happens within a few hours of the last occurance. Therefore, simply because I did not encounter the issue in Kali does not mean that it would never happen in Kali, or other OS’s

Comment: I have a DELL laptop and we have something called dell diagnostics. DO you have something similar for Acer? May be running that from Windows will tell you something? If this is not an option - then I'm afraid we have hit a `road-block`

Comment: I do not know of any diagnostic tool from the manufacturer. I have checked my windows logs and not seen any sort of errors, even in verbose mode. I can try creating my own event logger, but I don't think it's worth the time. After a bit of research though, my best guess is a low level IRQL error where there is a specific memory block that my keyboard drivers aren't being allowed to access when some very specific event has happened. I will look into that a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following methods can help you.

1. Just check if the `keyboard` can work fine, or the `USB port` works fine, you can use this keyboard on another PC to see if it is normal.
2. Configure the keyboard settings
   (1) Open `Setting` in `Start` menu
   (2) Open Easy of Access
   (3) Find `Keyboard` and click it
   (4) Find `Ignore or slow down brief or repeated keystrokes and adjust keyboard repeat rates` and turn off it
3. Just try to **reinstall/update/upgrade** the keyboard driver
4. Just try to **reinstall/update/upgrade** the USB drivers

Comment: It is a laptop, so the keyboard is not a usb keyboard. The drivers are the latest, and I have reinstalled them. I dont see what repeated keystrokes would have to do with it, since the entire keyboard stops working.